# How to control marked checkbox order in twig

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox, twig

So I'm facing this weird behavior when listing a series of checkboxes with twig

see the new page, it displays everything right, and saying that i'm saving this laboratory

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxlVM.jpg)
[image]

ok, I saved the laboratory, now went to the edit page

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ewxv.jpg)
[image]

the marked checkboxes displays at first, ruining the alphabetic order that was at the new page.

I need that the edit page become exactly like the new page, but I don't know how to organize these checkboxes on twig.

block that renders the checkboxes:

```
{% block _appbundle_laboratory_laboratoryExams_row %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="app-checkbox-collection">
                <p>{{ 'laboratory.field_laboratory' | trans }}</p>
                {%  dump(form) %}
                {% for child in form %}
                    {% if child.exam.vars.data.type == constant('AppBundle\\Entity\\ExamLaboratory::TYPE')%}
                        {{ form_widget(child.permission, {
                            'attr' : {
                                'class' : 'exam-checkbox'
                            },
                            'label' : child.exam.vars.data.name
                        }) }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <p>{{ 'laboratory.field_image' | trans }}</p>
                {% for child in form %}
                    {% if child.exam.vars.data.type == constant('AppBundle\\Entity\\ExamImage::TYPE')%}
                        {{ form_widget(child.permission, {
                            'attr' : {
                                'class' : 'exam-checkbox'
                            },
                            'label' : child.exam.vars.data.name
                        }) }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I don't ask at portuguese stackoverflow because no one answers symfony questions there, few users probably

EDIT:

Here is the buildForms:

Laboratory

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', null, array(
                'label' => 'laboratory.name',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'focus')
            ))                
            ->add('leader', null, array(
                'label' => 'laboratory.leader'
            ))                
            ->add('city', null, array(
                'label' => 'laboratory.city',
                'placeholder' => 'action.select_one'
            ))
            ->add('laboratoryExams', 'collection', array(
                'label' => 'laboratory.laboratoryExams',
                'type' => new LaboratoryExamType(),
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
        ;
    }
```

LaboratoryExam

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('permission', null, array(
                'label' => 'laboratoryexam.permission',
            ))
            ->add('exam', null, array(
                'label' => 'laboratoryexam.exam',
            ))
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the answers, i found a solution by resorting the ArrayCollection in the form.

```
$iterator = $form->get('laboratoryExams')->getData()->getIterator();
$iterator->uasort(function ($a, $b) {
    return ($a->getExam()->getName() < $b->getExam()->getName()) ? -1 : 1;
});
$form->get('laboratoryExams')->setData(new ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($iterator)));
```

IMO this should be done by default, I believe that no one would like to have the check-boxes disordered that way

Answer (score 2):

You can set the order of checkboxes while building the form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('permission', 'entity', [
       'class' => 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Parameter',
       'multiple' => true,
       'expanded' => true,
       'query_builder'=> function(EntityRepository $repository) {
            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('exam')->orderBy('exam.title', 'ASC');
        },
    ]);
}
```

Comment: did this but it gives me a series of select boxes instead of checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

I would say it has nothing to do with twig.

That would be set on the form type object where the form with checkboxes is constructed.

It seems the data is populated programmatically on form creation with already selected choices being first.

If it isn't the case or you got some problem, please edit your question with formtype code and code where you get the data for the checkboxes.